# Visual Studio Basics: Compiling specific files and finding references

Tags: visual-studio

I'm just getting started with Visual Studio (2010 Beta) and have some basic questions that I'm sure have easy answers:

1. When looking at sample code I often have a hard time finding the right things to add references to.  For instance, a sample program opens `System.ServiceModel.Web` but I can't find the required reference. `Web` doesn't exist in `System.ServiceModel` reference.  More generally, there doesn't seem to be a one-to-one match between namespaces that I see in code and the references to dlls I need add. The add references dialog has no search functionality so I find myself scrolling around trying to find the right dll.  Is the a better way?  Specifically, where's `System.ServiceModel.Web`?
2. Since I'm experimenting a lot, I often have many files that have all sorts of compile errors floating around.  When a try to build my project things explode with errors I'm not interested in. Is there any way to build just one file in a project?  Even errors in F# script files give me compile errors when I compile a project, even though they are just experimental notes.
3. Is there a way to "Debug" and run just one project in a solution, not the entire solution?  When I click debug, all these random projects start that I'm not interested in at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use the object browser functionality - View->Other Windows->Object Browser - you can do a search here and then by clicking on the top-level item in the tree there is a pane that shows the path to the DLL.

This shows that on my machine ServiceModel.Web is in C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll

2) You can exclude files from being built by changing the Build Action property for them to "None"

3) Similarly you can "Unload" projects from a solution (and then reload them later) by right clicking on them and selecting unload

Comment: I don't see Unload, do you mean Remove?

Comment: No - I mean unload but I must admit that I use it on VS2008 at work. On my VS Express edition at home I can't seem to find the menu item - which version of VS are you using?

Comment: ServiceModel.Web seems to be from the REST Starter Kit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx